# What will happen if I reverse the input shape of Conv1D?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Deep Learning. I would like to build a model from N timeseries. From some tutorials, I find that conv1D is used.

```
n_timesteps = 200
n_timeseries = 7
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timesteps,n_timeseries)))
```

However, my dataset shape was in `(n_samples, n_timeseries, n_timesteps)` and I trained the model with below layer

```
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_timeseries, n_timesteps)))
```

When I realised my shape is not same as the tutorial, I swapped it and still I am getting the same losses. (I was hoping loss will decrease)

So the question is, does the input shape matters for Conv1D?

Answer (score 0):

You have asked a very fundamental question.

For your fundamental question. I would like to answer it with some questions of my own.

- Would you be able to draw meaning from  a text that is in reverse order?(*maybe but very difficult*).
- Would you be able to draw meaning from a reverse order text if your language itself is written in reverse order lets say your language is arabic. ( *Yes then it would be easy*).

That means if you train your model with series data in certain order, the model will able to predict output for similar order series.

Swapping dimensions wont effect the performance of Conv Net. All the weight vectors will get swapped in similar oreder resulting in same loss.

lets say your initial input was of shape `(x1, y1)` which after training produced weight matrix of shape `(w1, w2)`.

Now if you change your input shape to `(y1, x1)` the resultant weight matrix will be `(w2, w1)`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. My initial input shape is (n_samples, n_timeseries, n_timesteps)